# Backbone Router Multiple Parameters; Second Parameter is Not Defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

My router config:

```
routes: {
    'report/:id': 'report',
    'report/:id/photo/:imageid': 'photo',
    'reportReadonly/:id': 'reportReadonly'
},
```

The photo route function:

```
photo: function (id, imageid) {
    ....
},
```

The hash I'm navigating to:

```
/#report/11/photo/7
```

When I break in the photo method the id is assigned correctly (11 in this case) but the imageid errors out that it's not defined. Not that the value of imageid equals undefined but not defined in that the variable was never declared. Hopefully I'm missing something simple?

Comment: Here's an example that works:http://jsfiddle.net/2vbebb7b/ , are doing the same thing?

Comment: The only thing I'm doing differently is navigating via a direct link <a href="/#report/11/photo/7">View Photo</a> instead of using navigate.history(). That shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Comment: err, I meant history.navigate(..)

Comment: What are you using the `#` in your url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link has a leading `/`, which means that

- it will behave as a normal link if you don't cancel the default actions
- and it won't trigger a `hashchange` event needed to fire a route

Use  `<a href="#report/11/photo/7">View Photo</a>` instead.

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/jbb836vp/1/

Comment: Thank you! Works as expected now.